# Completing some simple methods

Tags: java, methods

trying to complete some methods, which I think should be straight forward for someone with a bit of experience in Java. I'm a total noob :)

**Complete the method setXPosShark() which sets the x-position of the shark to the method's int arguement.**

```
    /**
    * Sets the x-position of the shark to the value of the argument
    */
    public void setXPosShark(int x)
    {
      // to be completed for part(i)
    }
```

Would this be:

```
    shark.setXPos(x);
```

?

**Complete the method setXPosSwimmer() which sets the x-position of the legs of the swimmer to the arguement x, the x-position of the body to x plus 10 and the x-position of the head to x plus 46.**

```
    /**
    * Sets the x-position of each of the legs, body and head of the swimmer. 
    * The x position of the legs is set to the argument, the x position of 
    * the body is set to the argument plus 10, and the x position of the  
    * head is set to the argument plus 46.
    */

    public void setXPosSwimmer(int x)
    {
      // to be completed for part(ii)       
    }
```

**Complete the method sinkSwimmer(). The method should move each component (head, body and legs) of the swimmer down by 50 units, and make the colour of each component blue.**
(

```
    /**
    * Makes the swimmer appear to disappear by increasing the 
    * y-position of each of the head, body and legs by 50, and 
    * turning their colour blue.
    */   
    public void sinkSwimmer()
    {
      //to be completed for part(iii)
    }
```

**Complete the method moveSimmer() which causes the compnents of the swimmer to move one unit to the right of their current positions.**

```
    /**
    * Causes the swimmer to move one unit to the right of its current position. 
    */
    public void moveSwimmer()
    {
      // to be completed for part(iv)
    }
```

Massive thank you to anyone that can help. I am working all through the nighht to try and complete an informal assignment (i.e. it is not graded) so that I can get the feedback returned before an upcoming assignment. Thanks, Ali

EDIT
My guesses are

For the second one:

```
    this.leg.setPosition(x); 
    this.body.setPosition(x+10); 
    this.head.setPosition(x+46);
```

Third one:

```
    this.legs.setPosition(y-50);  
    this.body.setPosition(y-50); 
    this.head.setPosition(y-50);
```

Fourth:

```
    this.legs.(this.legs() );
```

Not too sure about this one at all.

Here is a pastebin link to the full code I am working with (rather large):
http://pastebin.com/mF06jjSv

Comment: Show us what you have tried, then we might help if you have shown some effort.

Comment: are these in classes called `Shark` and `Swimmer`?

Comment: For the second one:
this.leg.setPosition(x);
this.body.setPosition(x+10);
this.head.setPosition(x+46);

Third one:
this.legs.setPosition(y-50);
this.body.setPosition(y-50);
this.head.setPosition(y-50);

Fourth:
this.legs.(this.legs() ); -- not really sure, bit lost!

Comment: that's not enough info, basically you need to write the method body of each of setXPos, Sink, Move, etc. so, you need to have somewhere a class defined with some private/public variables like SwimmerXPos, SharkXPos, and within the body of the methods you need to assign the value X(the parameter) to the private/public variable SwimmerXPos/SharkXPos, give us more code and we will try to help you understand

Comment: Here is a pastebin of the entire code I am looking at:
http://pastebin.com/mF06jjSv

Thanks for your help, I do appreciate it!

Comment: "I am working all through the nighht to try and complete an informal assignment (i.e. it is not graded) so that I can get the feedback returned before an upcoming assignment."  Curious: what is the point of getting feedback on solutions provided by SO community?

Comment: Put Shark and Swimmer classes in the question. That will give you a quick answer from any one of us here!!

Comment: I have edited the question now, hopefully that is enough information? Well I wish to submit a completed document with all solutions to this questions and the rest I have attempted. Sometimes the code provided by people outside of the course is not the code I am expected to provide. 

But at the moment just lost, very tired and really want to give up! Spent quite a while perservering with it and nearly done though :)

Answer (score 0):

(1) By complete the method you need to fill in the code to complete the method. So I'm assuming you have a shark class that might look something like this:

```
public class Shark {

    // ....all the methods you mentioned above....

}
```

Your class consists of two components called fields and methods. Methods are responsible for performing actions and modifying the data of a classes fields. The method `setXPosShark(int x)` would be responsible for changing a field which stores the X position of the shark.

Here is an example for the first method:

```
public class Shark {

     private int xPostion; // <-- this is a field.

     public Shark(int x, int y) {
          this.xPosition = x;
          // complete for the y.
     }

     public void setXPosShark(int x) {
          this.xPosition = x;
     }

}
```

Note: Notice how the field is private. It is recommended that all fields in a class are private and that the data in those fields interact through methods. This will protect data and allow you to validate and manipulating the data before storing it. In this case no validation is required. But in your second question you will need to modify the data before storing it by adding 10.

The importance of keeping fields private can be seen in your second question.

Assuming you have a class structure like so:

```
public class Swimmer {
    // total of 6 fields required for x and y positions of head, body and legs.
    private int headXPosition;
    private int bodyXPosition;
    private int legsXPosition;

    // Constructor should set each field to a default value (possibly 0).

   // Example of a setter method.
    public void setXPosSwimmer(int x) {
        this.headXPosition = x+46;
        // other two fields omitted... 
    }


    // Example of a getter method.
    public int getHeadXPosition() {
        return this.headXPosition 
    }

}
```

In `setXPosSwimmer(int x)` your not doing so much as validating the x value passed in as your doing some data manipulation before storing it. Manipulation in terms of adding 46 to the head and 10 to the legs and feet.

If you had made headXPosition or any of the other fields public another programmer (for example) could of set the headXPosition without adding the +46 which may cause a problem for your program. As this is a classroom assignment that would not be a problem but in the real world when it comes to making API's (programs that can interface with other programs) you would want to protect the data inside your programs objects.

Quick note on your classes:

The methods called set...() are known as setters they are responsible for setting the data the fields of a class hold. Since the data is private no other class can access it. If you try to call shark.xPosition; you will get a compile time error as xPosition is private. As such you will need to write a method to get (or retrieve) the data. These methods are called getters and use the convention get....() which will return the data. So in the case of the Shark class you may want to write a `getXPosition()` method that will: `return this.xPosition`.

For your third question you will need to add three more fields in the Swimmer class to store the Y position. You will also need to write corresponding setter and getter methods.

For the `sinkSwimmer` and `moveSwimmer` methods just adjust the corresponding fields. Same as you did for the `setXPosSwimmer(int x)` method.

Also after looking at your code I suggest you split things up into separate *.java files so it would be easier to work with. Since your a beginnger I would also use an IDE that can help you understand objects. I recommend using BlueJ which is free to download at: http://www.bluej.org/.

Also if you do not want to have 6 fields in the Swimmer class you could use a primitve array of int's like so:

```
...

private int[] head;
private int[] legs;
private int[] body;

// Constructor:
public Swimmer() {
    this.head = new int[2];
    // and so on... replacing .head with the other fields names.
}
...
```

`int[] head = new int[2]` Creates an array with two spaces [ 0 , 1 ] respectively. 0 represents the X position and 1 represents the Y position. This by calling this.head[0] returns an int representing the x position and so on.

As such setting an X postion on the head would be done like so:

```
...
public void setXPosSwimmer(int x) {
    this.head[0] = x+46;
    this.legs[0] = x+10;
    this.body[0] = x+10;
}
...
```